# Process.stdout.readline() doesn't output correctly

Tags: python

Im using Python 3.5, my code is as follows:

Given a_sentence the program hangs during the while loop because line_read is "" so it never increments nl_c, therefore never exits the loop, I'm relatively new to using sub processes so I'm not sure where the problem is,  whether it's not being read in correctly or the output.  tl;dr Output from subprocess is "" when it should be an arbitrary string.

Can someone point me in the right direction in getting the `line_read = proc.stdout.readline()` to be the line inputted above?

Comment: What is "a_sentence" anyway? You don't show its initialization. Not sure you gave us a MCVE of your problem.

Comment: a_sentence is just an arbitrary sentence string. I've edited the code to give an example.

Comment: Where is your call to `communicate()`?

Comment: There is none? From what I understand all that is necessary is the writing, flush, then `proc.stdout.readline()` to output the subprocess.

Comment: @RobertB - `communicate()` is a helper function that isn't needed if you do the process management yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`readline` returns a single line of text including the trailing new line until the stream is closed on the other end. Once all data has been read, it starts returning empty strings to let the caller know that the stream is closed and there will never be new data. Generally, while loops should break when an empty string is returned.

You should also call `proc.wait()` at the end so that system information about the dead process is cleaned up.

Comment: Then when printing `line_read = proc.stdout.readline()` shouldn't it return the string inputted a couple lines above?  My problem is that theoretically the string should be written to the subprocess, but it isn't outputted when I call `line_read = proc.stdout.readline()` because I try to print line_read and the first thing I get is "", not the string I initially entered.

Comment: That just means that the called process didn't work like you expected. You could check stderr and the return code for more details. But when readline returns "" it means that the subprocess has closed its output pipe and isn't going to give you more data.

Comment: Ok, I assume then its a problem with the subprocess. Calling stderr returns 'None' so I have no idea how to fix this, but thanks for your help anyways!